# get XML tags from URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

i'm trying to get some tags from the next xml file which is located here:
http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?version=581&appid=EBAYU91VTR1SQ8H917BC11O3BW8U4J&action=getResults&callname=FindItemsAdvanced&QueryKeywords=Aston+Martin+V12+Vanquish&categoryId=220

what do i need to do in order to get the "110" from the tags below:

```
<TotalItems>110</TotalItems>
```

using javascript?

Comment: You need to show us your code and explain your difficulties so we can see where you may be going wrong and advise you.

Comment: i'm trying to wrote a script which will take the value from the tag mentioned above and then i want to create a div somewhere in my code and place the value in it

Comment: my question is just how do i get the value out of the xml tag into my script?

Comment: Show us the script and explain the problem that you are having with it.

Comment: So you expect us to write one for you?

Comment: i want to write it but i don't know how to start since it's my first time with XML

Comment: no. i just want to know how do i get something using javascript from XML

Comment: Perform an ajax request to collect the XML as a string into a javascript variable, parse the string as XML and then use standard document methods or DOM traversal to get the information that you require.

Comment: Begin reading [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) then read [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and then [document API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example, it uses [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql) to bypass [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

```js
var pre = document.getElementById('out'),
    oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    url = 'http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?version=581&appid=EBAYU91VTR1SQ8H917BC11O3BW8U4J&action=getResults&callname=FindItemsAdvanced&QueryKeywords=Aston+Martin+V12+Vanquish&categoryId=220',
    yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from xml where url="' + url + '"') + '&format=xml&callback';

function updateProgress(oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
        pre.textContent = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total;
    } else {
        pre.textContent = 'Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown.';
    }
}

function transferComplete(evt) {
    pre.textContent = 'The transfer is complete.';
    
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(evt.target.responseText, "application/xml"),
        firstTotalItems = doc.getElementsByTagName('TotalItems')[0];
    
    pre.textContent += '\nTotalItems: ' + firstTotalItems.textContent;
}

function transferFailed(evt) {
    status.textContent = 'An error occurred while transferring the file.';
}

function transferCanceled(evt) {
    status.textContent = 'The transfer has been canceled by the user.';
}

oReq.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
oReq.addEventListener("error", transferFailed, false);
oReq.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled, false);
oReq.open("GET", yql, true);
oReq.send(null);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```